# Converting logarithm to decimal form

Tags: logarithms

I apologize if this is a poorly formatted question, but i really need some help here...

I am trying to solve the following problem: $4\ln^3$

When I input this into my calculator, I get $4.3944$. However, when i input it into mathway, I get $5.0136$, which is the correct answer. Here is a picture of it in mathway: [mathway_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ve3i.png)

I have spent the last $2$ hours trying to figure out how to properly convert this problem into decimal form, as well as why my calculator keeps giving me a different answer. But, since I am new to logarithms, I have not been able to figure out how to get the answer $5.0136$.

Could someone please tell me how mathway gets this answer? Also, why does my calculator give me a different answer than mathway? Am I inputting it incorrectly?

Comment: Given the image at the link, I find it hard to believe that your input to your calculator was actually $4\ln^3$, which should in fact not yield any numerical result; what did you actually input?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott  I put in 4ln(3) but i do not think that is the same as putting in 4ln^3. I have tried inputting it multiple ways but i still cannot seem to get the answer 5.0136.

Comment: You’re right: $4\ln 3$ is something completely different. But you’ve completely ignored part of the expression: what happened to the $11$ inside the logarithm and the $11$ in the denominator?

Comment: What do you mean $4\ln ^3$?  What does that *mean*?  Did you mean $4 \ln(3)$ or $4\ln^3 (something)$ (if so what?).  The phrase $4\ln^3$ doesn't mean *anything*.

Comment: Why are you leaving out the $11$?  That is an *essential* part of the problem.  Are you assuming you can cancel things out from *within* the expression?  For example would you think $\frac {2\sqrt{7}}{7} =  {2\sqrt{{\ \ }}}$?  But $2\sqrt{\ \ }$ is meaningless.  So is $4\ln^3$ is meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression in question is

$$\frac{4\ln^3(11)}{11}\;.$$

In this context $\ln^3(11)$ means $(\ln 11)^3$, just as $\sin^2\theta$ normally means $(\sin\theta)^2$; this is approximately $2.3978953^3$, or about $13.787662$. Now multiply that by $4$ and divide by $11$ to get about $5.0136953$.

Comment: That explanation made perfect sense! Like i said before i am new to logarithms so i was unsure what the proper form of this problem was. Thank you!

Comment: @MoistCarrot: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Input this into your calculator instead:

$$\frac{4\times (\ln (11))^3}{11}.$$

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely inputting it incorrectly into your calculator.
The answer you are getting is due to the following input:
$$4\cdot\ln(3)$$ which will give you 4.3944...

As others have noted already, try this instead.
$$\dfrac{4\cdot(\ln(11))^{3}}{11}$$

Using the parenthesis above might clean up some of the confusion especially if it's an older style calculator.